# Python Meta Client Copy 403 Head Object Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.config import Config
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
import json

def get_creds(role):
    session = botocore.session.get_session()
    aws_access_id = session.get_credentials().access_key
    aws_secret_id = session.get_credentials().secret_key
    aws_token = session.get_credentials().token
    
    return aws_access_id, aws_secret_id, aws_token

def create_connection(item, type):
    role = get_creds('arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/LambdaRole') 
    
    my_config = Config(
                        region_name='us-east-1',
                        signature_version='s3v4'
                        ) 
    
    if type == 'client' :
        c = boto3.client(item,
                        config = my_config,
                        aws_access_key_id=role[0],
                        aws_secret_access_key=role[1],
                        aws_session_token=role[2],
                        )
    else :
        c = boto3.resource(item,
                          config = my_config,
                          aws_access_key_id=role[0],
                          aws_secret_access_key=role[1],
                          aws_session_token=role[2],
                          )
    
    return c

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    src_bucket = 'source_bucket'
    dest_bucket = 'destination_bucket' 
    copy_to_prefix = dest_bucket + "/" + date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d") + '/'
    s3 = create_connection('s3', 'client')
    results = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = src_bucket)
    keys = []
    
    next_token = ''
    
    while next_token is not None:
        if next_token == '':
            results = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = src_bucket, Prefix =  'FBI/')
        elif next_token != '':
            results = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = src_bucket, Prefix = 'FBI/', ContinuationToken = next_token)
        
        next_token = results.get('NextContinuationToken')
    
    contents = results.get('Contents')
    for i in contents:
        k = i.get('Key')
        keys.append(k)

    s3_resource = create_connection('s3', 'resource')

    for k in keys:
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': '{}'.format(src_bucket),
            'Key': '{}'.format(k)
            }
        extra_args = { 'ACL' : 'bucket-owner-full-control' }
        s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_source, dest_bucket , copy_to_prefix + '{}'.format(k.split("/",1)[1]), extra_args)
```

This script is resulting in `"errorMessage": "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"`

The script does list the files, I can print(keys) and see the list.  It also is able to create the destination; I deleted the "sub-folder" and ran the script and it creates the entire structure.

It seems the problem is the actual get from the other account.

Bucket Policy on source account:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_bucket/FBI/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Inline IAM Policy for the role on destination account:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_bucket/FBI/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also added a bucket policy on the destination bucket matching the IAM policy, just to be sure.

Any ideas why I am seeing the error.

EDIT:

There was one point in time where the Account A cloudwatch showed "arn:aws:sts::803456671434:assumed-role/<role_name>/s3_session"

However, even adding that to the bucket policy has not changed the outcome.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add the AWS Account number of your source account in at least one of those policies depending on what apporach you are taking? I use delegated access so I had to create a trust policy which let my source account assume a role in destination account. You are using bucket policy it seems so you would have to specify it in there. Maybe you are missing that step?

Comment: I stopped assuming the role now; I am just using my account's ARN since it has permissions to the other account's bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out none of my code or permissions setup are the issue.  I was unaware that the files I am attempting to copy were actually loaded to the account I am trying to copy from by another account.

Here is the crux of what happens:

Account A (the originator account that I did not know about) -> Account B (the account I am trying to copy from), but does not give the ACL for bucket-owner-full-control.  Due to the lack of ACL updates Account C (my account) does not have permissions to the file, but it does have access to the bucket because Account B is the originating account for the bucket.

Possible solutions:

1. When Account A uploads the object to a bucket present in Account B, the object owner can provide permissions to both Account A and Account C by specifying canonical ID's via '—grant' option. In this case, the object owner (Account A) is directly providing access to Account C by mentioning in the ACL. Example `aws s3 cp /localpath/ s3://AccountAbucket name/ --grants-full id=AccountAcanonicalID_< Account B > id=AccountCcanonicalID_Account C
2. Account A uploading the objects normally to the bucket present in Account B by providing access to the bucket owner. Now, Account B can have an event notification triggering a Lambda function to overwrite the objects uploaded by Account A so that ownership of the objects is changed to Account B. In this case, the bucket and object owner would be Account B, then account B could set up bucket policy allowing Account C to access

There is possibly another solution that involves IAM role assumptions and setting up of chaining of roles.  Essentially IAM role in Account A Allows an IAM Role in Account B to assume it and then Account C assumes the Account B role.  That seems like a potentially cumbersome setup and the chaining could be complicated.